# Simple way to limit decimal places to two places

Tags: java, double, decimal

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {//begin main
    Scanner worksheet = new Scanner(System.in);
       {
        double radi;
        double area;
        double circum;
        double pie = 3.14;

        System.out.println("Enter the radius: ");
        radi = worksheet.nextDouble();//enter 1.2 

        area = pie * radi * radi;
```

Area comes out as 4.521599999999999, but I want it to be 4.52.

```
        System.out.println("The area is:" + area);

        circum=2*pie*radi;
```

`circum` comes out as 7.536.
want it to be 7.53

```
        System.out.println("The circumference is:"+circum);

    }
```

How can I truncate the value to 2 decimal places without a method.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far please? :)

Comment: Tag the language please

Comment: @Blackbam Looks like java. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println("The circumference is:"+df.format(circum));
```

or you can simply do this

```
int temp = (int)(circum*100);//452
circum = temp/100d;//4.52
```

Both of these will limit the value up to 2 decimal points.

Wish it will solve the problem.

[Reference (Take a look at this)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Welcome.@SonBramble